# Capybara & minitest - sessions aren't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capybara, integration-testing, minitest

I want Capybara to fill out a login form, click on 'Login', and redirect me to the root path like this: [(example)](http://garyrafferty.com/2011/09/29/Testing-devise-with-rspec-and-capybara.html).  This app is your classic blog app with Devise for authentication - I can't think of anything else that would affect the test.

I only get a 'failed assertion' test error so I checked the spelling of my button, experimented with Warden, and still couldn't figure it out.  For a solution, I'd like to be able to exactly mimic how a user would navigate through a page.

**Integration test:**

```
require 'test_helper'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
require 'database_cleaner'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

class PostsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

  # for setup and tear down each time we run tests                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

  setup do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    DatabaseCleaner.start                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

  teardown do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    DatabaseCleaner.clean                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

  def setup                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    @post = posts(:valid_post)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    @admin = users(:james)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    @regular = users(:steve)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

  test 'display comments' do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    assert @post.comments.first.body == 'hello'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

  test 'visit contact page' do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    visit '/contact'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    assert page.has_text?('jamesyoun710')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

  test 'login as admin' do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    visit new_user_session_path                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    assert page.has_field?('Email', type: 'email')                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    fill_in('Email', with: 'jamesyoun710@gmail.com')                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    fill_in('Password', with: 'gooneen44')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    click_on('Log in') # this doesn't redirect me into the page
    # login_as(@admin) # I need to do this to execute the line above
    visit root_path
    assert page.has_link?('Logout')
    assert page.has_link?('New Post')
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
end
```

**test_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
require 'rails/test_help'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
require "minitest/reporters"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
require 'minitest/rails'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

require 'capybara/rails'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
require 'minitest/rails/capybara'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Minitest::Reporters.use!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

# for creating sessions in tests                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
include Warden::Test::Helpers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Warden.test_mode!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

class ActiveSupport::TestCase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.                                                                                                                                                                                             
    fixtures :all                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

class ActionController::TestCase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  include Devise::TestHelpers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  include Capybara::DSL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
end
```

**gemfile**:

```
group :development, :test do                                                                                                                                             
  gem 'database_cleaner'                                                                                                                                                 
  gem 'hirb'                                                                                                                                                             
  gem 'byebug'                                                                                                                                                           
  gem 'annotate'                                                                                                                                                         
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'                                                                                                                                            
  gem 'spring'                                                                                                                                                           
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.1.1'                                                                                                                                        
  gem 'binding_of_caller', '~> 0.7.2'                                                                                                                                    
end                                                                                                                                                                      

group :test do                                                                                                                                                           
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'                                                                                                                                      
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'                                                                                                                                          
  # gem 'mini_backtrace'                                                                                                                                                 
  gem 'guard-minitest', '2.3.1'                                                                                                                                          
end
```

Comment: While its pretty tempting to squash everything into one test you should really follow best practices and split this into one assertion per test block. Doing it all in one test makes it harder (read impossible) to pinpoint what actually fails in your app. Signing the user in is one test. Creating the post is another.

Comment: Thanks Max - I'll split them out like you suggested.  For simplicity I deleted the extra lines on the test to focus on the login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - I should have been using login info from my fixtures (test db) but instead I was using login info from my development db.